# group chat room using XMPP in xcode iphone to support multiuser chat

Tags: xcode, xmpp, chat, one-to-many

I have implemented the one to one chat using xmpp. But for one to multiple users I tried to pass an array of recipients in "to" parameter,it sends my message to all of them but cant receive their messages. How can I use isGroupChatMessageWithBody for enabling the one to multiple chat?

Comment: What framework or library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

isGroupChatMessageWithBody won't work the way you are trying to use it.  It is a method that returns a BOOL based on whether or not the message is of type group chat.

Comment: i want, =>I have multiple group. and i when i click on particular group than i want presence only that(One) group.

Comment: @iPhoneDev ask a new question.